# How to make pgfplots obey non-rotated boundaries along the axes for a rotated graph?

Tags: pgfplots

I'm trying to rotate a simple Gaussian, but when I try to rotate the graph, it seems clear that `pgfplots` is simply cropping the graph to match the boundaries specified:

[image]

The above picture shows two graphs, one is blue and isn't rotated. This graph has the correct boundaries, x is between 0 and 5.

The other graph in orange is rotated. The graph is then cropped after rotating. I wish to reverse this order, so that I can have the shape of the blue graph, rotated like the orange graph.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}


\pgfmathdeclarefunction{gauss}{2}{%
  \pgfmathparse{1/(#2*sqrt(2*pi))*exp(-((x-#1)^2)/(2*#2^2))}%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=1,>=latex,
    declare function={
        normal(\m,\s)=1/(2*\s*sqrt(pi))*exp(-(x-\m)^2/(2*\s^2));
    }
]
\begin{axis}[
    axis lines=none,
    samples=30,
    xmin=0,xmax=5,
    domain=-5:5,
    area plot/.style={
        fill opacity=0.75,
        draw=none,
        fill=orange,
        mark=none,
        smooth
    }
]
\addplot [area plot,rotate=25,yshift=-50,xshift=50]  {normal(0,1)};
\addplot [area plot]  {normal(0,1)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A tikzpicture is still a tikzpicture. So you can apply transformations to it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{gauss}{2}{%
  \pgfmathparse{1/(#2*sqrt(2*pi))*exp(-((x-#1)^2)/(2*#2^2))}%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex,rotate around={50:(0,0)},% <-- Here
    declare function={normal(\m,\s)=1/(2*\s*sqrt(pi))*exp(-(x-\m)^2/(2*\s^2));}
]
\begin{axis}[
    axis lines=none,
    samples=30,
    xmin=0,xmax=5,
    domain=-5:5,
    area plot/.style={
        fill opacity=0.75,
        draw=none,
        fill=orange,
        mark=none,
        smooth
    }
]
\addplot [area plot]  {normal(0,1)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: For some reason I really like this!

Answer (score 2):

I don't know the relationship between `TiKZ's plot` coordinates and `pgfplots` so the results are not the same. But you don't need to use `pgfplots` to draw something like your example, just a `fill` with `plot` is enough and don't have to worry with clipped areas.

```
\documentclass[border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={%
    gauss(\x)=1/(sqrt(2*pi))*exp(-(\x)^2/2);},]

\fill[color=orange, fill opacity=.75] (0,0) --plot[ domain=0:5] (\x,{gauss(\x)}) -- cycle;

\fill[color=blue, fill opacity=.75,yshift=5mm, xshift=5mm, rotate=25 ] (0,0) -- plot[ domain=0:5] (\x,{gauss(\x)}) -- cycle;

\fill[color=red, fill opacity=.75,yshift=5, xshift=5mm, rotate=50] (0,0) -- plot[ domain=0:5] (\x,{gauss(\x)}) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

One impractical way to do this is by embedding the `tikzpicture` in a `rotatebox`, to then make that tikzpicture a node inside another `tikzpicture`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}


\pgfmathdeclarefunction{gauss}{2}{%
  \pgfmathparse{1/(#2*sqrt(2*pi))*exp(-((x-#1)^2)/(2*#2^2))}%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\node at (0,0){\rotatebox{45}{\begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=1,>=latex,
    declare function={
        normal(\m,\s)=1/(2*\s*sqrt(pi))*exp(-(x-\m)^2/(2*\s^2));
    }
]
\begin{axis}[
    axis lines=none,
    samples=30,
    xmin=0,xmax=5,
    domain=-5:5,
    area plot/.style={
        fill opacity=0.75,
        draw=none,
        fill=orange,
        mark=none,
        smooth
    }
]
%\addplot [area plot,rotate=25,yshift=-50,xshift=50]  {normal(0,1)};
\addplot [area plot,fill=blue]  {normal(0,1)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}}};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Almost any answer will beat this one since embedding tikzpictures in nodes is one of the seven deadly sins...